# Module-based login in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to create a module based login. I have different users for my application, Admin, Author, Editor and so on.

What would be the best approach to develop a login mechanism in CodeIgniter for this purpose?

Comment: hmmm like the certain actions which a user can do that relate to him. An admin can make users. An author can submit article etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
class MY_Controller extends MX_Controller{ //presumes you use hmvc

     // this is the main controller, it feeds data to its child(extended) controllers
     // use the protected keyword over the private keyword for methods and vars

     protected $user, $permissions=array(), $group;

     // define some permission constants to check with MY_Controller scope including
     // children(extended)
     const PERM_READ = 'read'; 
     const PERM_EDIT = 'edit';
     const PERM_DELETE = 'delete';

     // an alternative is to use bit and bitewise operations
     // tutorial here http://codingrecipes.com/how-to-write-a-permission-system-using-bits-and-bitwise-operations-in-php


     public function __construct(){
         parent::__construct();

         //check the session data and assign a user to the user var

         $this->user = ($this->session->userdata('user_id')) 
                     ? User::find($this->session->userdata('user_id')) 
                     : NULL;

         if($this->user !== NULL)
         {
             $this->_assign_group();
             $this->_assign_permissions();
         }
     }

     public function _assign_group(){
         return $this->group = $this->user->group;
     }

     public function _assign_permissions(){
        // permissions are stored as json object in the database
        // this works fine as we dont need to do a serach on the object
        // we simply store and return
        // {["read", "update", "delete"]}

        return $this->permissions = (array)json_decode($this->user->permissions);
     }

     public function _can_read(){
         return (bool) (in_array(self::PERM_READ, $this->permissions));
     }

     public function _can_edit(){
         return (bool) (in_array(self::PERM_EDIT, $this->permissions));
     }

     public function _can_delete(){
         return (bool) (in_array(self::PERM_DELETE, $this->permissions));
     }
}
```

-

```
class some_module extends MY_Controller{

    public function __construct(){
           parent::__construct();
    }

    public function module_method(){
        if($this->group === 'AUTHOR' AND $this->can_edit())
        {
            // you have access to edit this modules's content
        }
    }
}
```

Basically It checks for a session login and assigns a user to `$this->user`
Then once a user is assigned, it assigns their group and permissions.
You can now easily check these vars for matching strings/arrays

If you need to run a check inside your view you can do the following

```
<?php if(Modules::run('class/has_permissions_to_run_this')): ?>
<p>Good to load a view or print a form</p>
<?php else: ?>
<p>You need the correct credentials to view/edit this</p>
<?php endif;?>
```

**For Admins**

```
class Admin extends MY_Controller{

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        if( ! $this->_check_admin_credentials())
        {
            redirect('login');
        }

    }

    public function _check_admin_credentials(){
        return (bool)( 
            $this->_can_read()
            AND $this->_can_edit()
            AND $this->_can_delete()
            AND $this->group === 'admin'
        );
    }
```

-

```
public function for_super_user_only(){

        // if you need to block specific sections such as 
        // global settings or accounting from other admins
        // run the check inside the method itself
        if($this->group == 'super')
        {
            //continue;
        }
        else
        {
            show_404();
            //or display error view
        }
    }
```

*Your table structure might then look like this*

```
create table `users`(
`id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`group` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`firstname` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`lastname` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`alias` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`last_ip` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`permissions` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '["read", "update", "delete"]',
`active` boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`activation_code` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`password_token` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`last_login` datetime NOT NULL,
`created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
UNIQUE( `email` ),
UNIQUE( `alias` )
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT='Registered Users';
```

-- add indexes to rows that will be searched such as id,email,alias

```
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD INDEX( `id` );
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD INDEX( `email` );
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD INDEX( `alias` );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own Controller that check the different permission to access to a particulary area.
For Example you can create `Admin_Controller` and `Author_Controller` and in it do all the control staff.
To extend the main `CI_Controller` you need to create a new file in the "`application/core`" folder called "`MY_Controller`" and in it do your staff.

Example:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Admin_login extends CI_Controller{
     function __construct(){
          parent::__construct();
         //Your check staff
     }
}
class Author_login extends CI_Controller{
     function __construct(){
              parent::__construct();
             //Your check staff
         }

}
```

Then you can use it in your controller, for example:

```
class Admin_section extends Admin_Controller{

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Permissions. There are several pre-made options available, or you can build one from scratch.

Comment: A bit terse, don't you think? Needs more detail.

Comment: @davidethell: While I agree with you, it certainly matches the vagueness and quality of the question.

Comment: @david I could also have given him the google search link for "Codeigniter permissions", would you have downvoted that, too?